# Youtube search page inside my app

Tags: ios, parameters, uiwebview, youtube, search-box

in my app there are two textfield where you can perform a search on youtube.
The final search string produced is like the following:

```
@"http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=shakira+%22waka+waka%22&showsearch=0";
```

I pass it to a WebView and:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webaddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

This is what is displayed:

[image]

Is it possible to avoid display of search box, other search parameters (result type, uploaded) and display instead only a list of the retrieved videos?

Thank in advance, yassa

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the YouTube Data API (via the Google API) to do this.

w/ the API you can make a query and get back a list of YouTube Search Results which contain a video ID, thumbnails, title, description, uploader, etc.

General YouTube API details are [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/).

For the [Google API for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/), you'll find instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction).
The API contains some examples in the API you can refer to as well.